# "pageinit" event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, page-init

I have tried to get this work for hours.
Both test `pageinit` and `pageshow` on row 1 in login.js with no response at all, but the page is still being loaded and I not getting any javascript error when I run it in FF.

From index.html

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PSForum Notiser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
```

From login.html

```
<div id="loginPage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="content">    

        <form id="loginForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

From login.js (the part wish not running)

```
$("#loginPage").on('pageinit', function(){
    alert("Hello world!");
    console.log("loginPage is loaded");
    checkPreAuth();
    var form = $("#loginForm");
    $(form).on("submit",handleLogin);

    if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined) {
      $("#username", form).val(window.localStorage["username"]);
    }
});
```

I hope the wisdom of stackoverflow can help me find why `$("#loginPage").on('pageinit')` not firing?

Best regards

Comment: `$(document).on('pageinit', "#loginPage", function(){` check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3S2P3/